# I want to rename a file using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a.dsx file in the remote server which I wish to rename. I have ansible playbook that gets the artefacts from nexus, zips it and then unzips it to the remote server.
That unzipped file needs to be renamed.

```
unarchive:
  remote_src: yes
  src: {{destinationDir}}/{{artefactid}}-{{version}}.tar.gz
  dest: {{destinationDir}}
```

The filename which gets unarchived is djp-1.0.2-20200805.123-1.dsx
And i just want djp.dsx

Actually the filename which I mentioned is just an example.. The filename would keep changing everytime we do deployment. Can you please suggest how can I modify the move command then.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. Actually the filename which I mentioned is just an example.. The filename would keep changing everytime we do deployment. Can you please suggest how can I modify the move command then?

Comment: djp-1.0.2-20200805.123-1.dsx. --  what is the format of the source file name ? and what is the format of the target file name.....? Will it always be in the format you gave in the example ?

Comment: Both the source and target file will always have the same format i.e.. dsx. The only thing that will change is.. As of now the filename is djpSrcUs, the other time it could be djpSrcMax. That's it. I just want to remove the version number and other numbering part to make the name short.

Comment: ok when I say format, it is the pattern of the source and target file names. Do we need to take first characters of source file name and use it for target file name ? Will the source file name always starts with 3 alphabets and then - etc.,

Comment: Yeah. The pattern will always be the same.

Comment: Yes correct.. We need to take the frst characters only and the target file name will be those extracted character

Comment: Can you try the following steps:
`
1) set_fact to a variable: item.path is the file your want to rename
-set_fact:
     fname: {{ item.path | basename }}
2) 
- set_fact:
     prefix: "{{ fname | regex_replace('(\w+)-.*', '\\1') }}"
3)
- name: Rename file
  command: mv ./djp-1.0.2-20200805.123-1.dsx ./{{prefix}}.dsx
`

Comment: Okay.. Iam trying this.but the last mv command is mentioning the whole filename. The filename wont be similar every time. By this I mean, now the original filename is djp-1.0.2-20200805.123-1.dsx the other filename would be djp-1.0.3-20200905.663-1.dsx. So it would not be possible to evertime change the name in playbook.

Comment: Sorry. you can use fname variable from first set_fact instead of a static file name

Comment: Getting the error in the line set_fact: prefix: "{{ fname | regex_replace('(\\w+)-. *' ) }}.....its showing some missing quotes

Comment: prefix: "{{ fname | regex_replace('(\w+)-.*', '\\1') }}".     I have written it as it is, still showing missing quotes syntax error.

Comment: The error I mentioned earlier, I have managed to remove that error. Now I am stuck in the mv command as it is showing error in the mv command. mv {{destDir}}/{{fname}} .dsx {{destDir}}/{{prefix}}.dsx.  Please suggest.

Comment: what is the error u r getting ?

Comment: The error is:   missing quotes.. The offending line appears to be: mv:here

Comment: `mv {{destDir|quote}}/{{fname|quote}} .dsx {{destDir|quote}}/{{prefix|quote}}.dsx ` try this

Comment: Getting a new error now!! In the variable setting, '' the task include an option with undefined variable. The error was 'fname' is undefined

Comment: Is there something wrong while declaring item.path??

Comment: Please learn the behavior of ansible way.You have to find the path of the source file and then use it in the steps I mentioned....you can easily google that...But three steps I mentioned is the right direction.

Comment: Shall I add those steps as an answer ? Rest of these errors u get are basic which you can figure out as you learn more about ansible.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty close now... I just have one doubt though.. What will be the basename which you mentioned in set_fact: fname:(item.path | basename)

Comment: basename is the filter from ansible itself. There are several other filtes - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use mv command to rename the file just as you would rename in a file in your terminal. As discussed in the comments

```
1) set_fact to a variable: item.path is the file your want to rename -set_fact: fname: {{ item.path | basename }}. You also have to find the files first.
2) - set_fact: prefix: "{{ fname | regex_replace('(\w+)-.*', '\\1') }}" 
3) - name: Rename file command: mv ./djp-1.0.2-20200805.123-1.dsx ./{{prefix}}.dsx
```